# Game Center Crashes If I Cancel The Log-In EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code-1, address=0x70000000c)

Tags: ios, debugging, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access, game-center

When debugging my app, i get a crash.

the code that the debugger halts at is:

```
- (void) callDelegate: (SEL) selector withArg: (id) arg error: (NSError*) err
{
    assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
    if([delegate respondsToSelector: selector]) //CODE HALTS HERE
    {
        if(arg != NULL)
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: arg withObject: err];
        }
        else
        {
            [delegate performSelector: selector withObject: err];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Missed Method");
    }
}
```

This crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code-1, address=0x70000000c)` every time I cancel the game centre authentication.

Any ideas on how I can fix this, thanks..

P.S. Someone asked what my stack looked like, [so here is a pic of the stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eH6z.png)

Comment: what does your stack look like? have you tried zombies? looking at the number `0x70000000c` I see that it is two 32 bit words (or ints) with the values {7,12} which makes me think that you are probably using an uninitialized value somewhere.

Comment: Did you check if delegate is nil at that line? It is probably deallocated already there. Check with Instruments for zombies and take a look there.

Comment: thanks @GradyPlayer for your comment, I've updated the post with a pic of the stack. Not really sure what I'm looking for there? Additionally, i don't really know what to look for since I'm not actually calling this method myself, its the action following the cancel button as the game centre asked me to sign in...

Comment: Hi @Templar, thanks for your comment. I'm not really sure what you mean by zombies? lol... I'm pretty new to all of this... could you be a little more specific, thanks.

Comment: Failing all this, does anyone know a good & upto date tutorial on integrating game center into a cocos2d game? thanks

Comment: you haven't really given anything that we can help you with... you probably have some warning that you are ignoring... try runnyng static analyzer .. I suspect that maybe selector isn't really a SEL, or that delegate isn't the object that you think it is.

Comment: At least post the code where and how you assign the delegate, and how that delegate object is created. I could image you create and assign a delegate that ends up being deallocated because there aren't any strong references to it, and next time you send a message to it it crashes. Tips for google search: "xcode scheme zombie" and "xcode exception breakpoint"

Comment: @user3616904 If you could show us how did you declare `delegate` and where did you assign anything to it, it would be really helpful. Here, a zombie-tutorial : It's a bit old, but will help you : http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with my delegate references.

I ended up removing all my code and using a fantastic helper made by another programmer.

the link is here: https://github.com/ablfx/ABGameKitHelper